# Searching Within OLAP cube in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot, ssas, olap, cubes

I am connecting to an SSAS OLAP cube within Excel and creating a pivot table with it.

Is there a way to search through the cube hierarchies for certain fields, without having to expand through all the dimensions?

For instance, if I had a dimension "Color" that can be expanded into "Blue", "Red", "Green" and I wanted to search "Blue" without expanding the Color dimension.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Excel 2010 or 2013 this is available from any Filter pop-up - there is now a Search field that works fairly well.  For earlier versions of Excel you could try the Excel PivotTable Extensions Add-in:

http://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/